# creating a bipartite graph in R with igraph with specific edge list

Tags: r, igraph, bipartite

I am new in R and also igraph. I want to make a bipartite graph between two nodes sets (one has 2115 nodes and another one has 4) with specified edge list. It sound easy but I have lots of difficulties for constructing it and so far no result. I would appreciate any help. Here is my piece of codes:

```
library(igraph)
test <- graph.data.frame(file.choose(), directed=T)
edge <- read.table(text="e1 e2
779 958
779 1293
779 1503
1124 97
1124 151
2078 979
1970 344", header=T)
edgels <- graph.edgelist(as.matrix(edge))
g <- graph.bipartite(test, edgels, directed=T)
```

I don't know where my code is wrong and I guess it is all because I am new in this. Thanks so much for your helps.

Comment: What does test look like (use `head`) and what errors do you get ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Edgelist to construct affiliation networks from a bipartite graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42279831/using-edgelist-to-construct-affiliation-networks-from-a-bipartite-graph)

Answer (score 6):

Here's an exampe of how you can build a bipartite graph :

```
library(igraph)

#### create example input data
nodesSet1 <- 1:3
nodesSet2 <- 1:5
edgeList <- data.frame(S1=c(1,1,2,3,3,3),
                       S2=c(1,3,5,3,4,2))
####

### PREMISE :
### graph.bipartite function simply create a graph and add a boolean 'type' attribute
### to each vertex that indicate the partition of the vertex (e.g. TRUE first partition, 
### FALSE second partition).
### So, it's not strictly necessary to use that function to get a bipartite graph, but 
### you can use any method you like (or feel easier) as long as you add a 'type' 
### attribute. 
### Hence, in the following code I won't use graph.bipartite since I don't like it :)


# first we give prefixes to the nodes to discern the two partition
g <- graph.empty()
g <- add.vertices(g,nv=length(nodesSet1),attr=list(name=paste0('A',nodesSet1),
                                          type=rep(TRUE,length(nodesSet1))))
g <- add.vertices(g,nv=length(nodesSet2),attr=list(name=paste0('B',nodesSet2),
                                type=rep(FALSE,length(nodesSet2))))

# we need to turn edgeList into a vector (and using names instead of indexes)
edgeListVec <- as.vector(t(as.matrix(data.frame(S1=paste0('A',edgeList$S1),
                             S2=paste0('B',edgeList$S2)))))
g <- add.edges(g,edgeListVec)

# check if is recognized as bipartite
is.bipartite(g)

# let's plot it !
plot.igraph(g, layout=layout.bipartite,
               vertex.color=c("orange","green")[V(g)$type+1])
```

[image]

Comment: Hi digEmAll, thanks for your fast reply. But it doesn't work on my case. the main problem here is that In one node set I have 2115 nodes so I cannot specify it as you did. I I want to be more clear, I am using a prepared network data set and trying to make a  bipartite graph based on it and specified nodes in its nodes set. Therefore, I have a edge list that specified that which node is connected to which in the other node set. So, what you are suggesting is not really appropriate here. Do you have more suggestion? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Mmh, I'm not sure I understood you correctly... you have one big edge list (e.g. `A -> X, A -> X, B -> Y ...`)  and ONE node set only representing the nodes in one partition (e.g. `A,B, ....`) and you whant to infer the second node set by constructing the bipartite graph ... is it right ? Please correct me if I'm wrong, eventually posting a small example of your input and desired output...

Comment: Hi digEmAll, I finally manage to solve this problem, as I said before, I am totally new in R and igraph. amd my difficulties was because of I didn't understand the graph.bipartite function properly. Anyway, I understand it now and it is over. thank you so much for your time and concerns.

Comment: @tolou Could you put your solution as an answer, for future readers as myself? It's really helpful to see accepted answers to questions. Thanks