# Using Edgelist to construct affiliation networks from a bipartite graph

Tags: r, igraph

I have an edgelist that represents a bipartite network.

```
ID1 ID2
  1 123
  1 124
  1 125
  2 123
  2 126
  3 127
  3 123
  3 130
```

ID1 is one class of actors, ID2 is another class of actors . How do I assign the attributes for the actor classes (all vertices in ID1 as one class, all vertices in ID2 as another class) to use it for a bipartite network analysis. In addition, I want to extract affiliation networks from the bipartite graph as two seperate graphs and want to export them.

The code to reproduce the data frame can be found here

```
x<-as.data.frame(matrix(c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,123,124,125,123,126,127,123,130),8,2))
colnames(x) <- c("ID1", "ID2")
g <- graph.data.frame(x, directed=F)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. What's the desired output here? How does the graph `g` need to change?

Comment: In this current form I can not create a bipartite graph, but I could find no solution for assigning a value (according to the igraph documentation one class of  actors needs to be assigned the value TRUE, the other needs to be assigned the value FALSE in order to detect it as a bipartite graph) to a column. I hope this makes it a little more clear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically just need to assign a type attribute to the vertices using the data in your data.frame. For example

```
is_bipartite(g)
# [1] FALSE
V(g)$type <- V(g)$name %in% x[["ID1"]]
is_bipartite(g)
# [1] TRUE
```

This code such uses the names of the vertices to set all the ones in the first column to TRUE.

Comment: this is great! and way more easier that trying to figure how graph.bipartites works. thank you ! A quick note thought: People should be careful though as there is no check that names in ID1 are not all exactly different than the name in ID2. If it is the case (some names are shared in the two column) you will have link between node of the same type and thus problem when doing the projections. Easy fix is to add prefix/suffix to the column ; to be sure they won't be matched by mistake.  `x[["ID1"]] <- paste('ID1',x[["ID1"]])` or something similar should be enough!