# Bipartite projection not working in igraph

Tags: r, igraph

I am trying to get the projections of a bi-partite graph using `igraph`.
My bi-partite network has 9523 edges,  8313 are of type `FALSE` and 1210 of type `TRUE` - as the following two outputs confirm.

```
> length(V(bp_network))
[1] 9523
> table(V(bp_network)$type)

FALSE  TRUE 
 8313  1210
```

However, when I try to project them using

```
pr_networks = bipartite_projection(bp_network, multiplicity = TRUE)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in bipartite_projection(bp_network, multiplicity = TRUE) : 
  At structure_generators.c:86 : Invalid (negative) vertex id, Invalid vertex id
```

I have tried changing the type of the vertices to characters from boolean.

```
> table(V(bp_network)$type)

   A    B 
1210 8313
```

Now the same code gives another error:

```
Error in bipartite_projection(bp_network, multiplicity = TRUE) : 
  `NA' is not allowed in vertex types
In addition: Warning message:
In bipartite_projection(bp_network, multiplicity = TRUE) :
  vertex types converted to logical
```

What might be going on?

EDIT: The network is created from a data frame with two columns of Twitter usernames, each row corresponding to a follow relationship.

```
> names(elite_following_df)
[1] "user"      "following"    
> nrow(elite_following_df)
[1] 267442
> bp_network = graph_from_edgelist(as.matrix(elite_following_df), directed = FALSE)
> V(bp_network)$type = ifelse(V(bp_network)$name %in% elite_following_df$following, TRUE, FALSE)
> length(E(bp_network))
[1] 267442
```

Comment: Could you share some data? To make your code reproducible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that one of the edges was violating the bipartite property. In other words, one of the nodes that was meant to be type `FALSE` had an edge with another `FALSE` node. Leaving this answer instead of deleting the question just in case someone encounters the same error.

Comment: Thanks! Had the same error  because some edge name where the same ; this could happen when using the very handy solution given here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42279831/using-edgelist-to-construct-affiliation-networks-from-a-bipartite-graph ; was very useful to see that you had this error and found why!